# Flatness of maps of analytic rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness, condensed-mathematics

Reference: [Lectures on Analytic Geometry](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Analytic.pdf)

Let $f\colon(\mathcal A,\mathcal M)\to(\mathcal B,\mathcal N)$ be a map of analytic ring. There are several possible ways to pose the flatness:

1. Flatness as the base change functor $D_{\ge0}(\mathcal A,\mathcal M)\to D_{\ge0}(\mathcal B,\mathcal N)$ maps static objects (i.e. those in the heart) to static objects.

I hope that I am not mistaken. The base change functor preserves nuclearity: since the forgetful functor preserves small colimits, the base change functor preserves compact objects. Furthermore, the base change functor preserves trace-class maps. It follows that the base change functor maps basic nuclear objects to basic nuclear, and therefore preserves nuclearity as well.

2. Flatness as the base change functor maps nuclear static objects to nuclear static objects.

In commutative algebra, the flatness guarantees the Tor-independence of pushout diagrams of rings. The analytic analogue does not seem to be true in general:

3. Flatness: for all maps $(\mathcal A,\mathcal M)\to(\mathcal C,\mathcal L)$ where $\mathcal C$ is static, the pushout $(\mathcal B,\mathcal N)\otimes_{(\mathcal A,\mathcal M)}^L(\mathcal C,\mathcal L)$ is static.

The first implies the second. When the map $f$ is steady, the underlying condensed ring of the pushout coincides with $\mathcal C\otimes_{(\mathcal A,\mathcal M)}^L(\mathcal B,\mathcal N)$, and in this case, the first implies the third. Is it reasonable to only consider steady maps?

I wonder which one should be the "correct" one to be considered in general, and more relations (like inverse implications under reasonable assumptions) between these three.

---

**Update.** I thought that there is "the correct flatness" which works in nearly all situations, which does not seem to be the case, following Clausen's comment. In fact, I asked this question as a first step to understand whether classical algebro-geometric concepts like smooth maps, étale maps and syntomic maps generalize to all maps of analytic rings. This might be too optimistic, so maybe I could start with understanding the following special case:

Suppose that $A\to B$ is a flat map of discrete rings. Then when the map $A_\blacksquare\to B_\blacksquare$ satisfies the three conditions above respectively?

Comment: I don't actually see a precise mathematical question here, but let me point out that 2 does not imply 1 (solid A-modules mapping to solid A[1/f]-modules gives a counterexample) and that there are situations where you'd perhaps naively think the map should count as flat but where even 2 fails (rational localizations in rigid analytic geometry).  3 fails for those as well.  You really do need to restrict the class of maps f to ensure the derived pushout of analytic rings is concentrated in degree zero.

Comment: It might help to know exactly what situation you're interested in if indeed you are interested in a specific situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flatness in analytic geometry is an interesting question! As Dustin says, it comes with several important caveats.

First, open immersions may not be flat even in the weakest sense of the word. Here is an instructive example. Let $K$ be your favourite analytic field ($\mathbb C$ or $\mathbb Q_p$ will do) equipped with a reasonable analytic ring structure. Let $D$ be an open unit disc over $K$, which contains two disjoint open discs $D_1,D_2\subset D$. Then $M=\mathcal O(D_1)/\mathcal O(D)$ is a nuclear $\mathcal O(D)$-module; note that by analytic continuation, the map $\mathcal O(D)\to \mathcal O(D_1)$ is injective. After base change to $D_2$, this becomes the quotient of $\mathcal O(D_1\cap D_2)$ by $\mathcal O(D_2)$. As $D_1\cap D_2=\emptyset$, this is $0/^{\mathbb L} \mathcal O(D_2) = \mathcal O(D_2)[1]$. Thus, flatness fails, and there's no way to rescue this if you want a very general notion of "quasicoherent sheaves".

The good news is that at least the Tor-dimension for open immersions is bounded in these "usual" examples, by the dimension of the space.

Another interesting fact is due to my PhD student Lucas Mann. If $A\to B$ is a map of discrete rings that is syntomic (=flat + local complete intersection) and $A$ is a valuation ring, then $A_{\blacksquare}\to B_{\blacksquare}$ is of Tor-dimension $\leq 1$; if $A$ is a field, it is even flat. Here, I use "flat" (and Tor-dimension) in the sense of 1) in your question.

Regarding your last question: Note that if $A$ is discrete, then nuclear modules are just usual discrete $A$-modules, so usual flat maps of discrete rings are always flat in the sense of 2). For flatness in the sense of 3): Consideration of induced analytic ring structures shows that it implies flatness in the sense of 1). If one restricts to steady maps, it reduces to flatness in the sense of 1). For more general maps, I think this will get insanely hard to control.

Comment: I am not sure whether Tor-amplitude is "in general" enough. Previously I thought that one does not "need" flatness in derived geometry (this seems what Lurie said in the introduction of SAG). Later, I see that, some flatness seems necessary for descent. I heard from Bhatt the following example: $\mathbb Z_{(p)}\to\mathbb F_p\times\mathbb Q$ has finite Tor-amplitude and the base change functor is conservative, but it does not satisfy Čech descent.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "general enough". But Lucas Mann is proving these results as intermediate steps to proving descent. (He's able to prove some very strong descent properties in the perfectoid setting (on the $\mathcal O^+/p$-almost-level): hyper-v-descent!)

Comment: A similar example to Peter's comment was given in https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.11608 on page 16. It is for that reason that Kremnizer and I realized back in 2013 that the better way to define a topology is by using homotopy epimorphisms of derived connective rings (these rings themselves may happen to be homotopically discrete) as opposed to flat epimorphisms of homotopically discrete rings.